# Django: Get list of latest cost values by group

Tags: python, mysql, django, aggregate

I have the following Django model:

```
class Costs(models.Model):
  """Represents a cost for a vendor / locale combo."""
  valid_from_date = models.DateField()
  vendor_id = models.ForeignKey('Vendor')
  locale_id = models.ForeignKey('Locale')
  cost = models.FloatField()
```

In order to preserve historic data, when the cost changes for a vendor / locale combo, we just add a new entry into the table (rather than overwrite the old one) with a new `valid_from_date`.

It's fairly easy to get all of the data from the table with `Costs.objects.all()`.  It's also easy to get an individual vendor / locale's current value with `Costs.objects.filter(vendor_id=1, locale_id=10).latest()`.

What I'm interested in getting is all of the latest cost values for each vendor / locale combo.  So essentially running the `latest()` function over each combination and getting a list / queryset as a result.

For example, given the following set of data:

- Id: 100, Date: 2017-1-1, Vendor: 1, Locale: 10, Cost: $1
- Id: 200, Date: 2017-2-1, Vendor: 1, Locale: 10, Cost: $2
- Id: 300, Date: 2017-1-1, Vendor: 2, Locale: 10, Cost: $3
- Id: 400, Date: 2017-2-1, Vendor: 2, Locale: 10, Cost: $4
- Id: 500, Date: 2017-1-1, Vendor: 2, Locale: 20, Cost: $5

I would want the following data back:

- Id: 200, Date: 2017-2-1, Vendor: 1, Locale: 10, Cost: $2
- Id: 400, Date: 2017-2-1, Vendor: 2, Locale: 10, Cost: $4
- Id: 500, Date: 2017-1-1, Vendor: 2, Locale: 20, Cost: $5

I've read through the [aggregation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/) a number of times but can't seem to find anything that matches perfectly.

I'm using Django 1.10 with a MySQL backend.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it directly in Python.  I grouped everything into a dictionary of lists (with the key being the Vendor / Locale combo) and then just took the max from each list.  Essentially, this:

```
groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
for cost in Cost.objects.all():
  groups['{} {}'.format(cost.vendor_id, cost.locale_id].append(cost)
return [max(value, key=operator.attrgetter('date'))
        for value in groups.itervalues()]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you had postgres as a backend, you could use some `distinct('vendor_id', 'locale_id')` and be happy. As you don't, you have to be more creative:

```
from django.db.models import Max

ids = Costs.objects.\
    values('vendor_id', 'locale_id').\  # grouping based on values will be used for annotation
    annotate(mx=Max('id')).\      # annotate the max id for each group
    order_by().\                  # clear any default ordering to avoid a total mess
    values_list('mx', flat=True)  # retrieve all the max ids

costs = Costs.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

This shuold result in a single db query. All this can be arduously extracted from the [docs on the interaction of `values`, `order_by`, and `annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This seems like the right direction but I don't think it's quite there.  The id values are not guaranteed to be larger as date increases (historical data has been backloaded).  So just because A.date > B.date does not mean A.id > B.id.  If we annotate with `Max('date')` instead of `id` we then can't do the `Costs.objects.filter()` line.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to group on vendor_id and locale_id, annotate on max_date en still get the latest id?